# How to properly show Swagger UI models using Java Swagger Core

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-ui

I trying to generate my Data Transfer Objects (models for Swagger UI):[look for the site example, in the bottom of page. After the requests we have the models](http://petstore.swagger.io/?_ga=2.103706824.993048376.1505164113-1230320450.1505164113).

Here's my Jersey 2 JaxRS ResourceConfig:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class App extends ResourceConfig {
    private void confJersey2() {
        packages("vetorlog.api;");
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
    }

    private void confSwagger() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setTitle("Title");
        beanConfig.setDescription("Description");
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("example.api");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http", "https"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");

        register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
    }

    public App() {
        confJersey2();
        confSwagger();
    }
}
```

I have tried using `@ApiModel` swagger annotatations, without success.
Here's one of my DTO (model):

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ApiModel
public class ExampleDTO {
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;
    @JsonProperty("value_string")
    private String valueString;
    @JsonProperty("value_double")
    private double valueDouble;
}
```

EDIT: My swagger.json:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "DocumentaÃ§Ã£o das requisiÃ§Ãµes do projeto e interface de teste",
        "version": "1.0",
        "title": "Econometer"
    },
    "host": "localhost:8080",
    "basePath": "/api",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "example"
        },
        {
            "name": "hello"
        }
    ],
    "schemes": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/v1/example": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "example"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o GET com query params e retorno de JSON",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "getWithQueryParams",
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "interval",
                        "in": "query",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "page",
                        "in": "query",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int32"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "size",
                        "in": "query",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "integer",
                        "default": 100,
                        "maximum": 2147483647,
                        "minimum": 1,
                        "format": "int32"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "default": {
                        "description": "successful operation"
                    }
                }
            },
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "example"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o POST, com login e geraÃ§Ã£o de token com dados do header",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "postToLogin",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "put": {
                "tags": [
                    "example"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o PUT, com atualizaÃ§Ã£o de dados via JSON",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "putWithJson",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "delete": {
                "tags": [
                    "example"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o DELETE, com deleÃ§Ã£o de arquivo por Path Param",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "deleteWithPathParam",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "patch": {
                "tags": [
                    "example"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o PATCH, com atualizaÃ§Ã£o de alguns campos via JSON, com validaÃ§Ã£o",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "patchSomeFields",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/v1/hello": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "hello"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o GET",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "get",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "hello"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o POST",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "post",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "put": {
                "tags": [
                    "hello"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o PUT",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "put",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "delete": {
                "tags": [
                    "hello"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o DELETE",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "delete",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "patch": {
                "tags": [
                    "hello"
                ],
                "summary": "RequisiÃ§Ã£o PATCH",
                "description": "",
                "operationId": "patch",
                "produces": [
                    "text/plain"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://petstore.swagger.io uses Swagger UI version 3. The one you are using is likely 2.x. [Version detection](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/version-detection.md).

Comment: I added my swagger.json. It's showing the swagger version, which is really 2.0. How can I use the latest version? I cloned the swagger UI latest version.